# Server 2012 R2 w/ 2003 Active Directory / GPO

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

This is a really simple question, and while I think I know the answer for it, I can't back it up.

1. A server 2003 AD can work with a server 2012 RDS server, but can 2003 GPO be applied to a 2012 R2 RDS server as a result of that configuration?

We plan to migrate to 2008 AD soon, but time constraints have us in a severe bind, can anyone provide some insight here?  I seem to run into issues when applying ANY GPO.

If you need more information to answer this question, please let me know.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

While pegging away I found that 2003 GPO can be applied - so long as you have your permissions set up correctly.

I had incorrectly nested the affected RDS server in the wrong OU.